# is there an easy way to mark an entity in the cache as "added"?

Tags: breeze

i would like to set an entity sent from the server to "added". it looks like entityaspect has methods setdeleted, setmodified, etc... but i can't seem to find one called setadded... what is the cleanest way to set an entity to "added"? i was thinking perhaps i would need to detach and then attach as "added". i have a server method called "newdeal" which creates a new entity ready for data entry... this method has business logic which i would prefer to keep on the server... when it gets to the client the entity is marked as "unmodified" which makes sense... but i would then like to change it to "added"...

thank you

Comment: Have you find the solution? I have a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18515136/174638

Answer (score 1):

@giancarloa, I'm assuming that, by the time the entity is sent from server to client, it has been persisted in the database. If that's the case, it wouldn't make sense to have its entityState set to Added as it would cause a duplicate error. If that's not how it works, please explain in detail what you are doing as I'm trying to get an idea of all the steps you're taking.

I'm also confused as to why create an entity in the server, send it to the client, update it, and then send it back to the server to save it in the DB - this just appear to cause more traffic and possibly reduce performance. Also, what it the user decides not to save? - then the work in the server would've been wasted.

Why not create the entity in the client and if it turns out to be saved, then the business logic would kick in the server during the beforeSaveEntity/beforeSaveEntities?

Comment: hi sbelini... thank you for the response... actually the new entity is not persisted server side... the entity sent to the client does not exist in the database... there is a significant amount of business logic that needs to take place in order to set up the new entity for data entry, such as default values for primitives and non primitive (child entities) properties... i don't want this business logic on the client... i would prefer to leave it server side in the service layer... some of the default data needs to be present immediately... it can't wait for the save to happen first... thanks

Comment: Thanks for the updated. Provide details (snippets, if possible) as to how you are invoking the server method, creating the entity, and returning it to the client.

Comment: @giancarloa, let me clarify my last request. There is currently no way in Breeze to invoke a server method to do something and return it to the client. As of now, the only way of reaching out to the server is via named queries, save interceptors (beforeSaveEntity/beforeSaveEntities), and "named saves" (i.e. via resourceName). Maybe you got creative and used one of the situations above to accomplish your task, which is totally valid (kudos to you for that!); but we need to understand your workaround in order to look at the problem in depth and search for a possible solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The breeze expect that entities returned from the server already exists in your database. This is not the case if your server fetched the entities from some other sources (not the database), returned them to client and then user can decide to the client if those entities should really be inserted in the database.

As you indicated, what you must do is skip the code that adds the entities into client's entity manager. later, you can add the detached entities to Entitymanager.

See the following answer for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596070/174638